# Moment of Inertia of Cylinder through horizontal axis

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, moment-of-inertia

Regarding moment of inertia (MOI) of a **solid** cyclinder, I want to calculate the MOI through the horizontal axis (central diameter) which is the 2nd diagram in the figure:

[image: here]

I want to do so by using the *perpendicular axis theorem*.
If I assume it to be '$I_\text{horizontal axis}$' then by the perpendicular axis theorem

$$I_\text{horizontal axis}+I_\text{central axis}=I_\text{vertical axis}$$

I think you can imagine vertical axis on your own; I cant find a photo for it, but it's identical to the horizontal axis (just rotate horizontal axis by 90°).

We have

$$I_\text{horizontal axis}=I_\text{vertical axis}$$

which gives $I_\text{central axis}=0$.

What went wrong here??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The perpendicular axis theorem is only applicable for laminar bodies where the moment of inertia about an axis perpendicular to its plane is the sum of its moments of inertia about two mutually perpendicular axes in its plane and all three axes being concurrent.

To find the $_{horizontal axis}$ you could proceed with integration of disc elements or using the perpendicular axis theorem, parallel axis theorem and Routh's rule all together to obtain the value.